# Serve webApp from EC2 or S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, web-hosting

We have a java backend running on Glassfish, and a webApp of static pages that make ajax calls to update their content.

The backend will be hosted on Amazon EC2 (through Elastic Beanstalk). I'm wondering if we should serve those static pages from the same Glassfish hosts (on EC2), or whether it would make more sense to host those in S3 buckets instead.

It seems like a typical setup, but I haven't spotted any documents discussing the options. Does anyone have experience about this, and if so, what is the cost / performance relationship of those two approaches.

*Benefits that I see for the S3 hosting:*

- Changes can be uploaded easily without having to go through a full deployment exercise, restart servers, etc.
- Front-end code can be kept separately on its own repo
- Other?

However, we don't know if S3 scales as easily as the Beanstalk environment, if it is as performant (response time as simultaneous hits increase), and at what comparable cost.

*Disadvantages:*

- We'll have to deal with CORS
- Other?

Comment: If you search for something like "host static files on EC2 vs S3" you will find tons of discussions about this.

Comment: don't think about scaling on S3; think about it as scaling on S3 using CloudFront. S3 is not meant to be a general webserver.